# 8GB RAM is fullfilled, addressed /tmp /var/log into RAM

Tags: ssd, ram, fstab, storage

Ok, so I have 8GB memory and 30GB msata storage + some external drives...

30GB for ubuntu, no SWAP partition, only main /

Updated fstab to store /tmp and /var/log into RAM and Firefox caching into /tmp

But my RAM is filled very fast. I cannot run computer 24 hours without a problem. After long time I reach storage capacity of msata drive and RAM.
30GB is filled with ~/.cache/upstart (I just delete it :-D )
and RAM is filled.... I do not know reason.
Checked /var/log and /tmp but it is not big enough to fill my memory.

fstab:

```
UUID=d12c3921-b2d3-49d4-a55b-fd22683c4b6d /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
#
# Modification for SSD
tmpfs      /var/log        tmpfs      defaults,noatime        0    0
tmpfs      /tmp          tmpfs      defaults,noatime,mode=1777    0    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a closer look into the upstart directory to see what's getting big, but try changing the fstab attributes by removing the "noatime".  This is ram so that is not necessary like it is on the ssd (or other flash with limited lifespan).  I also don't use the defaults, but never actually run as long as you do.  Here's my settings, (ignore the ramfs difference and I think the size used to be ignored but is used these days):

```
tmpfs       /tmp        tmpfs   size=256M,mode=1777 0   0
ramfs       /var/log    ramfs   mode=755        0   0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited it like you do:
tmpfs      /var/log        tmpfs      defaults        0    0
tmpfs      /tmp          tmpfs      size=256M,defaults,mode=1777    0    0
Will watch any improvements :)

Comment: Found this: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ :D